# How to use multiple operators to a MongoDB aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with documents in this schema (yep, I know this is *schemaless world though*):

```
{
  name: "Real Colicos",
  fee: 123,
  creator: {},
  participants: [{},{}]
}
```

So, I need a **query where I can get first groups sorted by participants count**. Of course I could have a participantsCount attribute and increment it at update by using `$inc` but I feel it's a naive approach. Is this aggregation or map reduce realm?

## Edit. Solution is by using `aggregate`:

From [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) I could take this:

```
  db.groups.aggregate(
    [
      {
        $project: {
          name: 1,
          participantsCount: {$size: "$participants"}
        }
      }
    ])
```

**This works**. Now I wonder, how can I paginate the search, order by participantsCount and include only some document properties?

I've tried:

```
  db.groups.aggregate(
    [
      {

        $project: {
          name: 1,
          participantsCount: {$size: "$participants"}
        },
        $skip: 10,
        $limit: 5,
        $sort: {participantsCount: -1},
        $match: {isPrivate: false}

      }
    ],
    function (err, results) {
      console.log(results);
    }
  );
```

But throws `undefined` as result.

Also:

```
  db.groups.aggregate(
    [
      {

        $project: {
          name: 1,
          participantsCount: {$size: "$participants"}
        },
        {$skip: 10},
        {$limit: 5},
        {$sort: {participantsCount: -1}},
        {$match: {isPrivate: false}}

      }
    ],
    function (err, results) {
      console.log(results);
    }
  );
```

Which is throwing an empty array.

And even:

```
db.groups.aggregate(
    [
      {$project: {name: 1, isPrivate: 1, participantsCount: {$size: "$participants"}}},
      {$match: {isPrivate: false}},
      {$skip: 10},
      {$limit: 5},
      {$sort: {participantsCount: -1}}
    ],
    function (err, results) {
      console.log(results);
    }
  );
```

Which also throws an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer: Aggregation can be a pipeline.

From docs:

> The aggregation pipeline is a framework for data aggregation modeled on the concept of data processing pipelines. Documents enter a multi-stage pipeline that transforms the documents into an aggregated results.
>
> If your aggregation operation requires only a subset of the data in a collection, use the $match, $limit, and $skip stages to restrict the documents that enter at the beginning of the pipeline.

So this means a pipeline is processed to get the wanted results. And as second paragraph suggests, ***order in pipeline processing matters***.

This is how it must look like:

```
collection.aggregate(
    [
      {$match: {isPrivate: false}},
      {$skip: 0},
      {$limit: 2},
      {$project: {name: 1, participantsCount: {$size: "$participants"}}},
      {$sort: {participantsCount: -1}}
    ]
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see two immediate problems:

1. The stages are not properly pipelined. They are all part of one object at the moment but should appear as separate documents in the array:

```js
    db.groups.aggregate(
        [
          {$project: {name: 1, participantsCount: {$size: "$participants"}}},
          {$skip: 10},
          {$limit: 5},
          {$sort: {participantsCount: -1}},
          {$match: {isPrivate: false}}
        ],
        function (err, results) {
          console.log(results);
        }
      );
```

2. Nothing will pass the last $match because isPrivate was stripped at the first $project. You probably need to include that field in the $project.

Comment: I should have said to do all matches as the first stage so it can use indexes, otherwise the $project will need to do a bunch of work only to have the result stripped later.

Comment: Could you update your question to include this point you're commenting?

Comment: Hey thanks for updating your question to subvert my answer, then answer it yourself with the fixes that I suggested by without crediting me. Nice.